# 12 month moving average from Java array

Tags: java

i have tried to use this code to calculate 12 month moving average. i have the data below the third column is the value i would like to calculate the average on .
the problem with this code is that it outputs the moving average as the values converted to double

```
//a is an object of the larger class
//x is the collection of values to be averaged
public int bars = 1;
double[] movavg = new double[x.length - bars]; // 
int k = 0;
try {
    for (int i = a.bars - 1; i < a.x.length - 1; i++) // for each bar
    {
        a.movavg[a.k] = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < a.bars; j++) // sum over  'bars' previous input values
        {
            a.movavg[a.k] += a.x[i - j];
        }
        double k = a.movavg[a.k++] /= a.bars; // divide by number of bars

        System.out.println(i + "   " + k + "    " + a.avgNumerator[i]);
    }
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

---

```
year month  value_for_moving_average
2011   1    21333333
2011   2    13500000
2011   3    17285714
2011   4    15500000
2011   5    15800000
2011   6    15900000
2011   7    15875000
2011   8    15600000
2011   9    17666666
2011   10   20000000
2011   11   15958333
2011   12   21583333
2012   1    21519230
2012   2    25450000
2012   3    21400000
2012   4    34166666
2012   5    27928571
2012   6    29250000
2012   7    17550000
2012   8    19111111
2012   9    18200000
2012   10   15181818
2012   11   14455555
2012   12   16900000
2013   1    13500000
2013   2    13600000
2013   3    12812500
```

the result should be this

```
moving_average
15,868,750
16,446,875
17,228,571
17,098,113
17,056,140
17,512,727
15,891,379
16,056,923
16,188,571
16,515,385
16,270,833
16,671,053
17,241,279
18,296,196
18,547,222
19,431,548
20,334,302
21,014,706
21,089,080
21,520,349
21,408,333
20,737,500
20,745,876
20,493,229
19,597,849
18,323,656
17,704,167
```

but the output am gettin is this

```
2.1333333E7
1.35E7
1.7285714E7
1.55E7
1.58E7
1.59E7
1.5875E7
1.56E7
1.7666666E7
2.0E7
1.5958333E7
2.1583333E7
2.151923E7
2.545E7
2.14E7
3.4166666E7
2.7928571E7
2.925E7
1.755E7
1.9111111E7
1.82E7
1.5181818E7
1.4455555E7
1.69E7
1.35E7
1.36E7
```

its like the code is output the same values but converted to double

Comment: Why is this tagged mysql?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is actually asking. Do you want it as an integer?

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly your problem seems to be?

Answer (score 0):

> the problem with this code is that it outputs the moving average as the values converted to double

That is to be expected, since you calculated the averages as doubles.  If you simply want to convert the double averages to integers, then use [`Math.round(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29); e.g.

```
    System.out.println(i + "   " + k + "    " + 
                       Math.round(a.avgNumerator[i]));
```